# How to pop() a list n times in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a photo chooser function that counts the number of files in a given directory and makes a list of them. I want it to return only 5 image URLs. Here's the function:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, isfile

def choose_photos(account):
    photos = []
    # photos dir
    pd = join('C:\omg\photos', account)
    # of photos
    nop = len([name for name in listdir(location) if isfile(name)]) - 1
    # list of photos
    pl = list(range(0, nop))
    if len(pl) > 5:
        extra = len(pl) - 5
        # How can I pop extra times, so I end up with a list of 5 numbers
    shuffle(pl)
    for p in pl:
        photos.append(join('C:\omg\photos', account, str(p) + '.jpg'))
    return photos
```

Comment: You can slice the result list.  `pl[:5]`.

Comment: If you need a random selection of 5 items, use [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample).

Comment: wow, I didn't think about that one! post it as an answer so I can close this question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll go ahead and post a couple answers.  The easiest way to get some of a list is using `slice` notation:

```
pl = pl[:5] # get the first five elements.
```

If you really want to pop from the list this works:

```
while len(pl) > 5:
  pl.pop()
```

If you're after a random selection of the choices from that list, this is probably most effective:

```
import random
random.sample(range(10), 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'll accept it in 8 mins, SO isn't letting me now

Comment: somehow just `if` statement didn't work but `while` worked perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a list, you can just get the last five elements by slicing it:

```
last_photos = photos[5:]
```

This will return a shallow copy, so any edit in any of the lists will be reflected in the other. If you don't want this behaviour you should first make a deep copy.

```
import copy
last_photos = copy.deepcopy(photos)[5:]
```

edit:

should of course have been [5:] instead of [:-5]
But if you actually want to 'pop' it 5 times, this means you want the list without its last 5 elements...

Comment: That would return *all photos but the last five*. The correct way would be `photos[:5]` like g.d.d.c suggested.

Comment: This does not return 5 elements.  This will return 5 less elements than the length of the list.

Comment: @g.d.d.c I'm sorry, I thought he wanted to 'pop' the list 5 times, meaning getting back the list without the last 5 elements...

Comment: @JensTimmerman Then that ("the list without the last 5 elements") would still have been `photos[:-5]`. But `[5:]` would skip the first 5.

Answer (score 3):

In most languages pop() removes and returns the last element from a collection. So to remove and return n elements at the same time, how about:

```
def getPhotos(num):
    return [pl.pop() for _ in range(0,num)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and simple -

```
a = list("test string")
print(a[5:])#['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
a[:5] = []
print(a)#['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

Comment: The second solution is the best one here as it is inplace which is closer to `pop()`.

Comment: Exactly. The first one is to show how it works. Just reverse the slice and set it to an empty list.